# a problem in The Mean-Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Let $f(x)$ be defined and continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Prove that there is at least one number $c$ such that

$$\frac{af(a)-bf(b)}{a-b}=f(c)+cf'(c).$$

Comment: Consider the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=xf(x)$.

Comment: this is a duplicate problem of one a few days ago but i can't find it. does anyone else recall that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the mean value theorem to the function $x\mapsto x f(x)$ which satisfies the same hypothesis than $f$ does.

Comment: i still don't get the right hand side of the equation

Comment: Denote $\varphi$ this function, then $\varphi'(c) = f(c) + cf'(c)$... You get it, now ?

Comment: I still dont understand why: if f(x)=xg(x) then f'(x)=g(x)+cg'(x)

Comment: Ok that was my problem, forgot about that formula. i am still a beginner you see... thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: Yeah, no problem.